# Programming a simple series of keyboard shortcuts using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm an AHK beginner, been trying it out for a day. I've had some success but I'm stuck.

I want to use ahk to automate repetitive tasks done by existing keyboard shortcuts in a program called Shotcut (a video editor). So, in Shotcut I have a series of clips arranged one after the other on the timeline (I'll call them clip1, clip2, clip3 etc).

At present, using Shotcut's keyboard shortcuts, I press:

1. Alt+right arrow (to move cursor to end of clip 1)
2. Page Up (to move cursor backwards by 1 second)

..then I drag Clip 2 backwards over clip 1, to create a transition (no keyboard shortcut for this in Shotcut)..
Then..

3. and 4. Alt+right arrow TWICE (to move cursor to end of clip 2)
4. Page Up (to move cursor back by 1 second).
   ...etc etc (repeat this process).

So what I'd like to know is, how can I script ahk to:

1. Just automate steps 1 and 2 above (ie. Alt+right arrow then Page Up), by pressing, say, Ctrl+h in Shotcut....

and/or:

2. Just automate steps 3,4 and 5 above (ie Alt+right arrow TWICE, then Page Up)...

or, even better, could I:

3. automate steps 1, 2, then Pause ahk (while I drag the clips)... then continue with steps 3,4 and 5...?

I used the following to successfully just to get "PageUp" when Ctrl+h was pressed:

```
^h::
send, {PgUp} 
return
```

However I tried the following just for a solution just to get "Alt+right arrow" on pressing Ctrl+g but it didn't work -the cursor stayed still:

```
^g::
send, {!alt}
return
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: EDIT: I just solved the alt+right problem (above) by using^g::
SendInput !{right}
Return .. now I just need to find out how to get the shortcuts to run in succession.

Answer (score 2):

For sure you are on the right track. Use the help, especially the "Tutorial for beginners" also at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s1

So, just add them all together and optionally add some wait time between the steps to make sure the first one finishes, as follows:

```
^h::
    Send, {PgUp} 
    Sleep, 100  ;  optional delay (in milliseconds)
    SendInput, !{right}
return
```

Or try something like this:

```
^g::doSomething(A_ThisHotkey) ; ctrl+g presses alt+left
^h::doSomething(A_ThisHotkey) ; ctrl+h presses alt+right

doSomething(me){
    msgbox success! You pressed %me%
    Send, {PgUp} 
    Sleep, 100  ;  optional delay (in milliseconds)
    IfEqual, me, "^g", SendInput, {Alt Down}{left}{Alt Up}
    IfEqual, me, "^h", SendInput, {Alt Down}{right}{Alt Up}
return
}
```

Hth,

Comment: Thank you. Will try this tomorrow. Very grateful for your answer. Newbie question about posting here - how do I format my text so that code snippets come out in a grey box like yours do?

Comment: @JSR check edited answer.  Also, to get the code snippets, I use ctrl+q on a selection of text.  It has the effect of indenting the text 4 spaces (which also makes a code block).  Backticks (from the tilda key) `grey box` inline. There is formatting help on the right side of the edit screen or the ? icon on the right of the new question box.  It's simple markdown editing language.

Comment: Thanks, PGilm. I'm getting the hang of it!!

Answer (score 1):

PGilm provided a good example of how to combine the hotkeys. For the `Sleep, 100` in his setup you may want to replace it with `KeyWait, LButton, U` https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm

By implementing this you could cause the `SendInput !{right}` to trigger after releasing the mouse 1 button. You could add more `KeyWait, LButton, D` and `KeyWait, LButton, U` for however many total clicks it takes for you to drag clip 2 over clip 1 in your example.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow (after sleeping..). Very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PGilm and @ilhom - your replies gave me the kickstart I needed. My final code was

```
^h::
Send !{right}
Sleep 600
send, {PgUp} 
Sleep 2000
Send !{right}{Alt Up}
Sleep 600
Send !{right}{Alt Up}
Sleep 600
send, {PgUp} 
return
```

Works like a dream! I found I needed `{Alt Up}` after  `!{right}` or it didn't work.
(The code is pretty simple I know, but to me (a newbie), this has opened up a whole lot of creative possibilities for automating processes in Shotcut and other progs). Thks!!

PS sorry if it's not etiquette to answer on my own question......

Comment: Good stuff. See my edited answer if you sometimes need to go alt+left.  You will find in the help that it does mention that in sending keys it is best to hold them expressly.  For ctrl + c copying, for example, `Send, {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}` is apparently more reliable than `Send, ^c`.  So for you, `{Alt Down}{right}{Alt Up}`.

Comment: I may also mention, if the two alt + right steps in a row don't need any time in between, the multiple key presses work like this: `{Alt Down}{right 2}{Alt Up}`.

Comment: Brilliant advice, @PGilm. Yes, I plan to do more automations, including Ctrl-c and Alt+left, so your help is spot on!